# Patten searching in Python

Tags: python, regex

Python newbie here:

I'm trying to do a regex search on a text file.
For example if I had a text file like this:

```
Datetime somewords
Datetime morewords
Datetime somemorewords
Datetime  Merging 8 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
Datetime somewords
Datetime  Merging 2 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
```

I'm trying to extract the phrase:
     "Merging  files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"

The regex I am trying to use is below: But this will search for anything that has Merging and the number.

What is the best way I could combine the numeric and email address so that the parser returns the below output?

Desired output:

```
Merging 8 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
Merging 2 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
```

Regex i tried:

```
re.match('r'Merging\s*\d+\.{0,1}\d*\Files with Email Address\s*=\s*',line);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall` instead of `re.match`.

```
Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*'\w+@\w+\.\w+'\"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rZ8bG0/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Datetime somewords
Datetime morewords
Datetime somemorewords
Datetime  Merging 8 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'\"
Datetime somewords
Datetime  Merging 2 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'\""""
>>> m = re.findall(r'Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*\'\w+@\w+\.\w+\'\"', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
    print i


Merging 8 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
Merging 2 files with Email Address = 'someone@something.com'"
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much. Regex by itself works, but the full code gives an error..guess i'll open another question. Thanks again for your prompt response.

Comment: you need to escape the last `"` present in the input string.

Comment: Isn't it this way?   regex = re.compile(r'Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*\'\w+@\w+\x\w+\'\\"'). I get the "sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\x'" error..

Comment: sorry i donno. Maybe you could ask it as another question with a link to this question.